# Access data after a header structure

Tags: c, struct, network-programming

I am doing some network programming, and I use some `struct` to describe my frame header like that:

```
struct my_frame_header {
    uint16_t field1;
    uint16_t field2;
};
```

And so, when I have a buffer frame I can do something like that:

```
uint8_t buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
struct my_frame_header *frame_header = (struct my_frame_header *)buffer;

my_read(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
```

I can now access to the header field like that:

```
ntohl(frame_header->field1);
```

Now, my question is: **What is the most elegant way to access the data after the structure?** *(i.e. to get a pointer at the beginning of the data part)*

Comment: This breaks strict aliasing rules, doesn't it?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't known [this rule](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule). But it seems that, by using an `uint8_t buffer[]` it is ok.

Comment: I would say thats right, but not at all. I suppose if you are on a machine with CHAR_BIT > 8 you will get trouble. But I can't confirm, as I never worked on such machine.

Comment: @Zaibis Not really, I am running this on a microcontroller, so it should be ok. Thanks for the information

Comment: My concern is, the Standard states that only `char`, `unsigned char` and `signed char` or equilent sized types pointer are allowed to alias in that way. So If you are on a i.e. 16 bit machine, you would break that rule by aliasing it with `uint8_t`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if I understood your question correctly, you can do something like

```
uint8_t * data = (uint8_t *)buffer + sizeof (struct my_frame)
```

then, `data` will be a pointer to the next `uint8_t` element after the header.

Comment: Thanks, I also thought to this solution, but for me it is not very elegant.

Answer (score 1):

```
uint8_t buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
struct my_frame_header *frame_header = (struct my_frame_header *)buffer;
```

This is wrong, the base address of `buffer` can be unaligned for `my_frame_header`.

Take  look to [Memory access and alignment](http://lwn.net/Articles/260832/)

On the other hand:

> The block that malloc gives you is guaranteed to be aligned so that it
>   can hold any type of data.

Then, you can use `malloc` in order to skip this problem:

```
uint8_t *buffer = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);
```

Comment: Not an answer, but very useful. Thanks. As suggested in the article, I will add some compiler directive to correct this.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am running this on a microcontroller with endless loop tasks (freertos) and data on the stack. So I will really need to check this out.